# Using gpu::GpuMat in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, cuda, gpu

I would like to know how can I modify a `gpu::GpuMat`. In fact I would like to know if it is possible to use a `gpu::GpuMat` like a `cv::Mat`.

I would like to do something like that:

```
    cv::namedWindow("Result");
    cv::Mat src_host = cv::imread("lena.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    cv::gpu::GpuMat dst, src;
    src.upload(src_host);


    for (unsigned int y = 0; y < src.rows; y++){
        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < src.cols; x++){
            src.at<uchar>(y,x) = 0;
        }
    }

    cv::Mat result_host;
    dst.download(result_host);
    cv::imshow("Result", result_host);
    cv::waitKey();
}
catch(const cv::Exception& ex)
{
    std::cout << "Error: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
}
return 0;
```

It seems to be not possible. Does someone know an alternative ?
Do I have to download my `gpu::GpuMat` to a `cv::Mat` each time I want to make something ?
Thanks in advance

Edit: I could probably use `gpu::PtrStepSz` (have to test...)

Comment: I don't really see how this is a CUDA programming problem. Perhaps you could remove the CUDA tag from the question?

Comment: I want to use gpu::Mat which is provided by Opencv over Cuda...

Comment: Yes, but nothing in your code or question is actually anything to do with CUDA, only OpenCV classes which tangentially refer to abstractions with CUDA buried inside them somewhere. By the same logic you should tag your question with "windows" or "linux", because your code runs OpenCV over the top of the operating system as well....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`GpuMat` is allocated in GPU memory. You can't modify it from CPU code. You can

1. Set all matrix pixels to the same value (`setTo` method).
2. Fill data on CPU using `cv::Mat` and then upload it to `GpuMat`.
3. Implement your own CUDA kernel and fill `GpuMat` in it.

Comment: Thanks ! that's what I was thinking ... :/