# How to fill each cv::Mat Column with a different value in OpenCV C++?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on OpenCV GPU.
I want to know, can we access `GpuMat` elements directly in C++ code?.
With little knowledge of this thing not being possible.
I am downloading data from GPU memory to CPU memory and then accessing the elements using 'at' operator.

But I need something like this :
For a 2x3 matrix :
The elements should be filled as follows :

```
Mat abc(0 , 0) = 1;
Mat abc(0, 1) = 2;
Mat abc (0 , 2) = 3;
Mat abc(1 , 0) = 1;
Mat abc(1, 1) = 2;
Mat abc (1 , 2) = 3;
```

i.e. , to fill every column with a different value.
Using the 'at' operator in for loop is time consuming.
Is there any API or some other way to do it in less time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using gpu::Mat in Opencv C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679470/using-gpumat-in-opencv-c)

Comment: @Aurelius Could you please explain ur comment...

Comment: The linked question also asks how to manipulate data in a `cv::GpuMat`. The answer there suggests `setTo()`, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: setTo() sets all the element of a GpuMat to the same value. I want to set every column with a different value. There is an option of getting rectangular sub-matrix , but for large size matrices , iterating it in a for loop wont be good in terms of performance

Comment: Right. And you should be able to create a ROI and fill that.

Comment: `at<>()` is slow. Use the efficient image scanning technique at http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#the-efficient-way. It have found it to be more than 5x faster than `at()`. I think @Aurelius has the right way though.

Answer (score 3):

`GpuMat` offers much of the [same functionality](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/data_structures.html#gpu-gpumat) as `cv::Mat`. You can create a submatrix with `col()` and use `setTo()` to fill it with data:

```
cv::gpu::GpuMat gm(3,3,CV_8UC1);
for (int i = 0; i < gm.cols; ++i)
{
    auto column = gm.col(i);
    auto val = cv::Scalar(i + 1);    // This value is just to reflect your example.
    column.setTo(val);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. I didnt know about the col() .

Comment: I ll just try this and check the performance , if the performance degrades(compared to CPU)... I will be needing some other way to do it.

Comment: Is there no way to do this without a for loop ,as with the for loop ,the execution time will depend on the number of columns in the matrix.more the number of columns , greater the execution time

Comment: @user2100866 I don't see an obvious way to avoid a loop without manually setting the index. Why do you want to avoid loops? Also, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14551017/1601291) might be helpful when thinking about performance.

Comment: I have posted a question with the title  : "cpu-gpu-performance-comparision" wherein , I found that implementing the same operation(addition) in a for loop using C Style Open Cv API and GPU API results in performance difference where GPU performance is degraded and it degrades more on on increasing the iterations of for loop. Currently I am poritng my CPU based Code into GPU to gain performance improvement.